# Error when calling overloaded assignment operator: "undefined reference to..."

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, assignment-operator

I need some help with an error I am running into when trying to call the overloaded assignment operator (operator=) that I have created in a file of mine called longint.cpp. Whenever I try and use the operator= to create a copy of a LongInt object, I get the following error:

```
> g++ main.cpp longint.cpp 
/tmp/ccSt5VIK.o: In function `operator<<(std::ostream&, LongInt const&)':
longint.cpp:(.text+0x57): undefined reference to `LongInt::LongInt(LongInt const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**When I do not try and use/call the overloaded assignment operator, then I can get my code to compile correctly. However, when I do call the overloaded assignment operator, like in the operator<< function, I get the error shown above. Can someone help me identify what is causing this**

**longint.cpp:**

```
#include "longint.h"

//istream &operator>>(istream &in, LongInt &rhs){
  //return in;
//}

ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, const LongInt &rhs){
  cout << "entering the operator<<" << endl;
  
  //I want to create a copy of the LongInt being passed in.
  //I will then use that copy to print out the Deque object of the LongInt being passed in (the Deque object is called digits)
  //I will print out the Deque objects in a similar way to how it is done in the deque_test.cpp file
  //Like this:
  //  while (!deque1.isEmpty())
  //    cout << deque1.removeFront() << endl;
  
  LongInt tmp = rhs; 

  while (!tmp.digits.isEmpty()){
    cout << tmp.digits.removeFront();
  }
  cout << "" << endl;
  
  return out;
}

//Constructors
//Here I want to go through the entire string and add all the values to the string in the correct order in the string.
LongInt::LongInt(const string str){
  cout << "constructor w/ str input" << endl;
  int i = 0;
  while (str[i]){
    digits.addBack(str[i]);
    i++;
  }
}

//LongInt::LongInt(const LongInt &rhs)

LongInt::LongInt(){
  cout << "constructor w/no parameters" << endl;
  digits.addBack('0');
  //cout <<"getBack of default constructor: " << digits.getBack() << endl;
  //cout << "size of current digits deque: " << digits.size() << endl;
  negative = false;
}

// Destructor
LongInt::~LongInt(){
  digits.clear();
}

// Arithmetic binary operators
//LongInt operator+(const LongInt &rhs) const;
//LongInt operator-(const LongInt &rhs) const;

// assignment operators
const LongInt &LongInt::operator=(const LongInt &rhs){
  cout << "enter operator=" << endl;

  this->negative = rhs.negative; //Set the new LongInt sign to the RHS sign.
  this->digits = rhs.digits; //Here I should be setting the deque of the LHS to the deque of the rhs

  cout << "branch A" << endl;
  return *this;

}

// Logical binary operators
//bool operator< (const LongInt & rhs) const;
//bool operator<=(const LongInt & rhs) const;
//bool operator> (const LongInt & rhs) const;
//bool operator>=(const LongInt & rhs) const;
//bool operator==(const LongInt & rhs) const;
//bool operator!=(const LongInt & rhs) const;
```

Comment: `undefined reference to LongInt::LongInt(LongInt const&)'` error clearly shows that it is about a copy constructor which is not defined and not the assignment operator. You have to provide also a definition (body) of the copy constructor for the class `LongInt`

Comment: Honestly, I would also recommend trying to come up with a non-destructive way to iterate over your `Deque` class. If the only way to print out the contents of a `Deque` is to create a copy and call `removeFront` repeatedly until the copy is empty, something's gone wrong.